# LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE EXISTS. Are they equivalent?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, exists

I would like to create equivalent MySQL query using LEFT OUTER JOIN to WHERE EXISTS. I am following this question:

[Are the SQL concepts LEFT OUTER JOIN and WHERE NOT EXISTS basically the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775693/are-the-sql-concepts-left-outer-join-and-where-not-exists-basically-the-same)

This is the original query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableA.tableA_id = tableB.tableB_id
JOIN tableC ON tableC.tableC_id = tableB.tableB_id
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tableD
    WHERE tableA.employee_id = tableD.employee_id AND tableC.tableC_datum = DATE(tableD.tableD_od_datetime)
)
```

But this query return different values:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM tableA
JOIN tableB ON tableA.tableA_id = tableB.tableB_id
JOIN tableC ON tableC.tableC_id = tableB.tableB_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableD ON tableA.employee_id = tableD.employee_id AND tableC.tableC_datum = DATE(tableD.tableD_od_datetime)
WHERE tableD.employee_id IS NULL AND DATE(tableD.tableD_od_datetime) IS NULL
```

Why are these two outputs not equivalent, please?

Comment: LEFT JOIN does not remove any row from "base" table **but can multiply it** rather than NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @Akina yes, therefor I use `WHERE tableD.employee_id IS NULL AND DATE(tableD.tableD_od_datetime) IS NULL`. Or how can I do it better, please?

Comment: Both queries should return same rows. The first one will contain extra columns though, those from left joined table. What is your question?

Comment: @SalmanA The second query contains extra columns. I dont want these extra columns and my question is, if I can get the same number of columns in the second query as I have from the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `not exists` and `left join ... rgt.col is null` approaches are identical. The `left join` however will contain columns from the unwanted table so just be specific with the `select` clause:

```
SELECT table_a.*, table_b.*, table_c.*
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b ...
JOIN table_c ...
LEFT JOIN table_d ...
```

I would rather avoid `*` at all and explicitly list exactly those columns that I need.

Comment: does not work. Why should be `SELECT * ` different from `SELECT tableA.*, tableB.*, tableC.*` ?

Comment: `SELECT *` will select columns from **all tables present in the from clause**. In my example you're telling MySQL that I want columns from table a, b and c, but not d.

Comment: thanks. And `LEFT JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ?

Comment: The `outer` keyword is optional. `left join` means `left outer join`, no difference at all.

Comment: and the remaining `WHERE tableD.employee_id IS NULL AND DATE(tableD.tableD_od_datetime) IS NULL ` is correct?

Comment: The best would be `WHERE tabled.<whatever primary key here> IS NULL`.