# Convert inner select query to join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to convert my SQL query to Join.
I have two tables.

table: MATCH

| ID | Match_Id | User_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

table: BLOCK

| ID | Block_Id | User_Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |

Now from the above tables, I want to get the list of MatchIds which are not blocked.

I solve this problem using nested select queries, But I want to solve this problem using the JOINs.
I prepared the below SQL and it is working.

```
SELECT M.Match_Id
  FROM match M
 WHERE M.user_id = '1'
   AND M.match_id NOT IN
       (SELECT B.block_id 
          FROM block B 
         WHERE B.block_id IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Can you have null in block_id column? If no just change the join in the @DhruvJoshi answer with `on match_id = block_id` And the where `block_id is null`. If you can have null in the column I don’t think you can use a join

Comment: @Pp88 Yes we can have null in the Block table. Like BLOCK | ID | Block_Id | User_Id | | -- | -------- |--------| | 1 | null | 1|

Answer (score 0):

If you do a left join on the block table and look for null records on the join, that is effectively a NOT EXISTS query

```
SELECT M.Match_Id
FROM match M
LEFT JOIN Block B ON B.block_id == M.match_id
WHERE M.user_id = '1' 
AND B.Id IS NULL
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775693/are-the-sql-concepts-left-outer-join-and-where-not-exists-basically-the-same)

Comment: "==" operator in MySQL, really?